# constraint on overlapping intervals in postgres records

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, intervals

So I am making a booking system and I have the following table for reservations.

```
CREATE TABLE reservations (
    user_id INT REFERENCES users (id),
    booth_number INT REFERENCES booths (booth_number),
    starts DATE NOT NULL,
    ends DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, booth_number)
);
```

and I would like to know if it is possible to put a constraint on a database level that disallows insertion on overlapping reservations on the same booth?

e.g

```
INSERT INTO reservations( user_id, booth_number, starts, ends)
VALUES 
(1, 0, CURRENT_DATE, CURRENT_DATE + 7),
(2, 0, CURRENT_DATE + 4, CURRENT_DATE + 9),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Almost the exact scenario(room instead of booth) is in the docs:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-CONSTRAINT

*You can use the btree_gist extension to define exclusion constraints on plain scalar data types, which can then be combined with range exclusions for maximum flexibility. For example, after btree_gist is installed, the following constraint will reject overlapping ranges only if the meeting room numbers are equal:*

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gist;
CREATE TABLE room_reservation (
    room text,
    during tsrange,
    EXCLUDE USING GIST (room WITH =, during WITH &&)
);
```

To modify for your use:

```
EXCLUDE USING GIST (booth_number WITH =, daterange(starts, ends, '[]') WITH &&))
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: would you recommend having two seperate date columns or a single during tsrange column should the interval be prone to frequent updates?

Comment: I'm partial to separate date columns as I usually find that I am only updating one or the other and with a range field you have to include both values every time you update.

Comment: I prefer using `[)` instead of `[]`, as the `ends` could be `starts` in another record. However, does it work for a use case where a single `ends` per `booth_number` could be a `null`? I still want to make sure that `starts` of that row is within another record’s interval.

Comment: @tukusejssirs. 1) The point of the OP's question was to not allow overlap. In any case per [Discrete Range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-DISCRETE): `select daterange('2024-01-23'::date, '2024-01-31'::date, '[]'); [2024-01-23,2024-02-01)`. 2) `select daterange('2024-01-23'::date, null, '[]'); [2024-01-23,)` See [Infinite(unbound) ranges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-INFINITE): *Likewise, if the upper bound of the range is omitted, then all values greater than the lower bound are included in the range.*

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, my point is the same: the intervals should not overlap, however, I want to allow starting a new interval where the previous (per `booth_number`) left off, e.g. `('2024-01-23', '2024-01-24')` and `('2024-01-24', '2024-01-30')` should be allowed, however, `('2024-01-26', '2024-02-01')` after those those intervals should be prohibited.

Comment: Read the links I posted. Short version the canonical form for a `daterange` is `[)` per my examples in my previous comment.  Therefore you need to be aware that whatever `daterange` you start with will be rewritten to a `[)` form e.g. `select '(2024-01-23, 2024-01-24)'::daterange` becomes `empty`.